# Rails permit nested array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ngresource

I am trying to use **accepts_nested_attributes_for** in conjunction with a **has_many** association and having a lot of trouble...

Here is a simplified version of my **user.rb**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :user_permissions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_permissions
  ...
end
```

My **user_permission.rb**:

```
class UserPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

And my **users_controller.rb**:

```
class UsersController < ApiController
  ...    
  def update
    @user.assign_attributes user_params
    if @user.save
      render partial: 'user', locals: { user: @user }
    else
      render json: {errors: @user.errors}.to_json, status: 500
    end
  end  
  ...
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, user_permissions_attributes: [ :user_id, :resource_id, :can_read, :can_update, :can_create, :can_delete ])
  end
end
```

I am referencing [this rails documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) on how to use accepts_nested_attributes_for with Strong Parameters.

However, when I '*puts user_params*' from inside the users_controller this is all I see (no reference to the user_permissions):

```
{"first_name"=>"Joe", "last_name"=>"Shmoe"}
```

Here is an example of JSON I am submitting to the server (via angular $resource):

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Shmoe",
  "user_permissions": [
    {
      "organization_resource_id": 20,
      "user_id": 10,
      "can_update": true,
      "can_read": true
    },
    {
      "organization_resource_id": 21,
      "user_id": 10,
      "can_create": true,
      "can_read": true
    }
  ],
}
```

Which returns this JSON:

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Shmoe",
  "user_permissions": [],
}
```

I am fairly confident this is an issue in my rails layer, but just for reference here is the angular **User.js** service I created to perform this RESTful interaction with the server:

```
angular.module('slics').service('User', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/users/:id', {
      id: '@id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT',
        isArray: false
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Really not sure what I am missing here. It does not seem like it should be this difficult to submit nested attributes... but the more research I do the more I realize this does seem to be a pretty common Rails frustration.

Please feel free to comment if any additional context/information would be useful to include in my problem description to help troubleshoot this problem and I would be happy to provide it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you post an array of *hashes*, not a hash.

So this code

```
user_permissions_attributes: [ :user_id, :resource_id, :can_read, :can_update, :can_create, :can_delete ]
```

will permit such structure

```
 {
  "id": 10,
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Shmoe",
  "user_permissions_attributes": [    
      "organization_resource_id": 20,
      "user_id": 10,
      "can_update": true,
      "can_read": true
  ]
}
```

Try to whitelist all params at "user_permissions"

```
user_permissions_attributes: []
```

Or check out this article, to learn how to build advanced whitelists with StrongParams
http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/6/16/a-rule-of-thumb-for-strong-parameters

Comment: That `permit` call will actually not allow the JSON payload you show as an example. `user_permissions_attributes` will be allowed, but not `user_permissions`.

Answer (score 1):

Strong params expects `user_permissions_attributes`, and you're submitting `user_permissions`.

Strong params is separate from `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (in fact, it has nothing to do with it), so however you define your `require!`/`permit` calls is exactly how your attributes should be submitted.

**ProTip:** To save you some future frustration, if you plan on updating through accepts nested attributes, you probably want to permit `:id` as well.

Answer (score 0):

user_permissions_attributes: [ :user_id, :id, :can_read, :can_update, :can_create, :can_delete ]) permit :id and submitting hashes with index value..

JSON format submitting to the serve

```
"user": {
   "id": 10,
   "first_name": "Joe",
   "last_name": "Shmoe",
   "user_permissions": {
     "0": {
       "id": 20,
       "user_id": 10,
       "can_update": true,
       "can_read": true
      },
      "1": {
        "id": 21,
        "user_id": 10,
        "can_create": true,
        "can_read": true
      }
   }
}
```